# Get Title of External Page on Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to print the title of an external page on my page, without needing to load the former on the server side.

Currently, I'm using jQuery with Google's search API. Behold the hackyness of the following solution:

```
//Use google search api to get page title for link
var url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?q=" + **URL** + "&v=1.0&callback=?"
//Set URL for link
$("#link").attr("href", content);
//Execute google api JSON query
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  //Insert the unformatted title of the first result into the page
  $("#title").append(data.responseData.results[0].titleNoFormatting);
});
```

^works great, but only for pages indexed on Google who are the first result when the URL is submitted.

Who can do better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), example query for getting the title:

```
select * from html where url="http://cute-kittens.tumblr.com/" and xpath='//head/title'
```

Try it out yourself in their [console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//cute-kittens.tumblr.com/%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27//head/title%27).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting. YQL is a great solution. I ended up using their URL API.

Comment: YQL Console is down since fall 2017. Could you please suggest any good alternative to get a title of an external page? Thank you in advance!